# gtk3 can not be compiled with vte

Tags: c, gtk3, vte

I'm trying to integrate a terminal on my `Gtk3` app but when i compile the app,
i got that error.

```
(csimpleide:9858): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in  the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

because the `vte` lib use `gtk2`.

i use this command to compile.

```
gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 vte`
```

how i can resolve this ??

Comment: You should define a version for the `vte` library. What is your current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a `gtk3` based VTE library version, on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC, the appropriate `vte` version is `2.90`, so the compilation command would be:

```
gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 vte-2.90`
```

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was the solution.